# JQuery IDE for animations (flash like IDE)

Tags: jquery, user-interface, animation

Is there any IDE for desktop or web app, for create complex animations in jquery? something like Flash IDE?

I'm a developer, and I develop almost everything using notepad++. But now I have to create a site that normally will be developed in flash. I want to use JQuery because I'm sure javascript have all the characteristics to create the same kind of sites one can create using flash. I guess I can create it manually with notepad++, but an IDE will be very helpfully.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

)It's not an IDE, but you can use tools like http://jsfiddle.net/
Also libraries like http://raphaeljs.com/ and http://processingjs.org/ are very helpful (and available inside jsfiddle).

Comment: Following a link from raphael site, I found Sencha Animator (http://www.sencha.com/products/animator/). What do you think about it?

Comment: Ups, only for webkit browsers :(

Comment: I guess most tools like this will use HTML5, hence will target webkit and possibly IE9. But not the older (broken) IE6,7,8

Answer (score 1):

I guess you have to stay with notepad++.

Answer (score 0):

yes, there is from the visitmix lab. [Try Glimmer](http://visitmix.com/work/glimmer/)
Edit: It is nowhere near Flash IDE but worth a try.